# Simulating BJT 2N2222 in LTspice. 5 mA collector current when B and E shorted

Tags: bjt, npn, 2n2222

I am simulating NPN 2N2222 in LTspice. When I short base and emitter, the collector has peak up to 6 mA. Should not it be in terms of nA when there is 0 V between base and emitter?

Can you please describe what is going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What did you see with a scope ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4DoI.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fast rise and fall times (both 10 ns in your case) appear as a high frequency content. So the internal capacitances of the BJT (C<sub>μ</sub> and C<sub>π</sub> – remember the high-frequency model) come into play.

Since B and E are shorted, the C<sub>π</sub> disappears, and the C<sub>μ</sub> appears as a low resistance across collector and base during those fast rise and fall times. *If you look at the 2N2222 model you'll see that capacitance is given as 8 pF, and we take the 10-ns rise as a sine wave with a frequency of 1/10ns = 100 MHz then we can say that there's a ~200 Ohm resistor across the base and collector.*

So, what you are seeing is not the collector current, actually. Instead, it's the current that flows from the collector terminal through the collector-terminal resistance and the collector-base capacitance (reactance) to the ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmajqy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can verify this by looking at the emitter current (you'll see a negligible amount of very short peaks) and the base current (same amplitude as the so-called collector current but different sign).

---

The currents will decrease if you increase the rise and fall times.